# How to add Persistent History Tracking to already existing NSPersistentCloudKitContainer

Tags: swift, xcode

As I said in the title I have a core data container created in a custom class

```
    static var context: NSManagedObjectContext {

        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        context.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        return context
        }

    // MARK: - Core Data stack

    static var persistentContainer: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer = {
        /*
         The persistent container for the application. This implementation
         creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
         application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
         error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        */
        let container = PersistentContainer(name: "App")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {

                print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        let description = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first
        description?.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description!]
        return container
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

   static func saveContext () {
        let context = PersistanceService.persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                print("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }


        }
    }
```

And I’ve included the NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey but the debug prints this error when saving :

File is in Read Only mode due to Persistent History being detected but NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey was not included.

Comment: I've just run into this, too. Did you ever find the solution?

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: Make sure to set the description before `loadPersistentStores`.